# In Pine, Can I Create an Alert to Open Trade when 10 MA > 20 MA > 100 MA?

Tags: pine-script

It's easy to setup an alert to open a trade when for example the 10 MA crosses above the 20 MA, however how can I incorporate a 3rd MA in there?

I want it to open a trade when the 10 MA crosses above the 20 MA, but only when both of them are above the 100 MA.

Many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> It's easy to setup an alert to open a trade when for example the 10 MA crosses above the 20 MA, however how can I incorporate a 3rd MA in there?
>
> I want it to open a trade when the 10 MA crosses above the 20 MA, but only when both of them are above the 100 MA.

You can program those alerts like this:

```
//@version=3
study(title="My Alert Script", overlay=true)

// Calculate values
fastMA   = sma(close, 10)
mediumMA = sma(close, 20)
slowMA   = sma(close, 100)

crossUp   = crossover(fastMA, mediumMA)
crossDown = crossunder(fastMA, mediumMA)

// Determine alert conditions
alertUp = crossUp and (fastMA > slowMA) and
     (mediumMA > slowMA)
alertDown = crossDown and (fastMA < slowMA) and
     (mediumMA < slowMA)

// Create alerts
alertcondition(condition=alertUp,
     title="MA crossed above other")
alertcondition(condition=alertDown,
     title="MA crossed below other")

// Colour background
bgColour = alertUp ? green : 
     alertDown ? red :
     na

bgcolor(color=bgColour)
```